# How to clear a KivyMD MDList (remove all of the Items)?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How to clear a KivyMD MDList of all of the dynamically created Items? Example:

```
for x in range(10):
   item = OneLineListItem(text=str(x))
   self.List.add_widget(item)
```

We've got a list with 10 items now. I want to create a function that will remove all of them leaving the list empty. Is there any inside function to get something like that?

Comment: `self.List = []` ? The content is getting garbage collected then.

Comment: are you looking for `.clear()`??

Comment: I'm talking about KivyMD. When you have a MDList class I'm adding multiple OneLineListItem/s. After that I want to delete all of them from the list.

Comment: You can clear list just like python lang does. Or you can use clear_widgets() on these Item's parent.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try `list.clear()`. that would remove all the elements of the list.

```py
a = [1,2,3]
a.clear()
a
Out[4]: []
```